# Why does Voronoi texture sometimes have black lines through it?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, procedural

I was working with procedural nodes, and I added this Voronoi texture. **(See Photos)** I turned it to distance to edge, and turned the randomness value down to 0. Then I opened up a new Blender file, and re-created it, but for some reason, it looks different. The Voronoi texture doesn't have those vertical black lines, and I can't seem to re-create it. Does anyone know how I can re-create that look?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on the plane? Did you try applying scale and merging duplicate vertices as well as checking your normal orientation? And could you specify the build version of Blender you used?

Comment: If all things in the files are equal, then you've discovered a bug.  The fact that it's object coordinates shouldn't matter; the nature of your geometry shouldn't matter either, modifiers shouldn't matter if I'm thinking through it clearly  If you can reproduce it, make a bug report.  If you can't reproduce it, then neither can we, so neither can we troubleshoot it.  If not all things in the files are equal, then we'd need more info-- we'd need access to see whatever *wasn't* equal.  So, the file.  Expected voronoi output for what you're showing in your shader is the bottom image.

Comment: Is the face axis-aligned in the oject's local space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to re-create it. It has to do with where the object is in 3d space. (See Attached Photo) If the object is higher or lower, it will either have the black lines, or not. So depending on if you want the black lines or not, you can tab into edit mode, select the object, and move it around slightly.

I find double tapping the R key, and using the trackball rotation, works pretty well to change the result, but you have to do it in edit mode, or apply the objects rotation every time you rotate it and I didn't realize it until now, but my original object was slightly rotated in 3d space. So that caused to black lines to appear.

[image]

Comment: For some reason It won't let me accept this as the answer for two days. So I will mark this as solved as soon as it lets me do so.

Comment: You could switch the Voronoi to 2D also

Comment: Oh yeah, that gets rid of the black lines. I actually want the black lines though, but if for some reason I didn't I could do that. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid moving the object in space, you can use a mapping node to adjust the coordinates used by the 3D Voronoi.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks!